# Angular2 - Not looking in 'node_modules' for specific Module

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, node-modules

I'm trying to implement Firebase's authorization for Google, Twitter etc.

Following [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/angular-2-authentication-made-easy-with-firebase-246c282d9ef8#.hymci8tud) guide, showing me to call the following commands

```
npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
npm install @types/firebase`
```

and adding this to `tsconfig.json`

```
"typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "firebase",
      "node"
    ]
```

Now the problem I have is when trying to import the classes/modules from the `angularfire2` module, my browser returns a 404 on `localhost:3000/angularfire2` while all other node_modules are retrieved succesfully from `localhost:3000/node_modules/...` how can I make sure that my app looks into `node_modules` for this specific call?

(followed every instruction in the guide mentioned above -- all code is exactly the same, if neccessary I can provide it from my own code or a file-tree if neccessary).

Comment: do you use webpack or systemjs?

Comment: @smnbbrv systemjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also let systemjs know about the modules.

Go to your systemjs configuration and add a mapping for your library in there. Check the [systemjs documentation](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md) for more information.

Something like:

```
...
var map = {
  ...
  'angularfire2': 'node_modules/angularfire2',
  'firebase ': 'node_modules/firebase',
  ...    
};
...
...
var packages = {
  ...
  'angularfire2': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  ...
};
...
```

Check the paths to be the correct paths in the node_modules.